# displaying & styling strings in dynamic array

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, string, dynamic

I am new to js and am trying to find ways to display & style strings in an array above images.

JS:

```
NEW_COMMENTS = ["five", "six", "seven"];    

function testFunction()
{
    var log = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
    var srcOne = "rdmImg.jpg";
    var srcTwo = "specificImg.jpg";

    imgContainer = document.getElementById("container");

    img = [];
    for (i = 0; i < log.length; i++)
    {
        img[i].src = srcOne;
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(img[i]);
    }
}
```

All images are assigned to srcOne and set to srcTwo if clicked. Suppose img[0] is clicked (not shown), then img[1],img[2],img[3] will display log[1],log[2], and log[3] respectively.

The issue is that the 'log' array always contains index 0 and so despite img[0] is clicked, it will still display a comment. How do you make it so that when any srcOne image is clicked, it will NOT display a comment while the other srcOne images will display comments?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: You may have to do some work to clarify what your desired functionality is. This is very difficult to understand.

Comment: why dont you create an array of objects and attach log and image to it, rather than creating a separate array for log and image. Eg. create array like `const imageData  = [
{img: '__path to image', log:'__image log'},
{img: '__path to image', log:'__image log'},
...
]`

Comment: @AkhilAravind in the actual code, I actually have 15 images and am not too sure which algorithm would be more abstract.

Comment: @RobertL honestly I dont understand your requirement, what I understand is show a log WRT to an image change, right

Comment: sorry what's WRT?